# Google Wallet sandbox subscriptions always set at $0.00

Tags: android-pay

I'm trying to create a subscription with the google wallet API and in the checkout flow the user sees the following just before they confirm the order.

http://postimg.org/image/ulkxqundp/

So far so good.

However, when I view the subscriptions in my payee's sandbox, they value is always $0.00, despite it being reported at £2.00 (GBP) before.

The JWT object from one of the orders is pasted below. I'm a little stuck as to what to do next.

```
{
    "aud": "Google", 
    "iss": 6316919635690407920, 
    "request": {
            "initialPayment": {
                    "paymentType": "prorated", 
                    "price": "2.00", 
                    "currencyCode": "GBP"
            }, 
            "recurrence": {
                    "price": "2.00", 
                    "frequency": "monthly", 
                    "currencyCode": "GBP", 
                    "startTime": 1386899035
            }, 
            "sellerData": "{\"order_id\":\"6\"}", 
            "name": "Name", 
            "description": "Description"
    }, 
    "exp": 1384310635, 
    "iat": 1384307035, 
    "typ": "google/payments/inapp/subscription/v1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Has the order been `Charged` (by Google)? **Until then** what I see in my sandbox for `Net Revenue` is 0.00.

Screenshot below shows `Net Revenue` now correctly showing value less Google fees (was 0.00 prior to being `Charged`). The `Order history` shows the progress - so at 2:17, it was 0.00, then at 2:19, value is updated.

[image: Sandbox screen shot]

Hth...